# C++:array functions

Tags: c++

How can I write a program that reads in, a collection of characters from the key board and outputs them to the console. Data is input at random, but output selectively. Only unique characters are displayed at the console. Therefore, every character should be displayed once, no matter how many  times it appears in the array.

For example, if an array

```
Char letterArray[ ] = {B,C,C,X,Y,U,U,U};
```

The output should be:

```
B,C,X,Y,U
```

This is what I have done so far...

```
char myArray [500];
int count = 0;
int entered = 0;
char num;

while (entered < 8)
{
    cout << "\nEnter a Character:";
    cin >> num;

    bool duplicate = false;
    entered++;

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        if (myArray[i] == num)
            duplicate=true;
    }

    if (!duplicate)
    {
        myArray[count] = num;
        count++;
    } // end if
    else
        cout << num << " character has already been entered\n\n";

    // prints the list of values
    cout<<"The final Array Contains:\n";

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        cout << myArray[i] << " ";
    }
}
```

Comment: Whats the problem or question?

Comment: Do the characters need to come out in the same order they were entered?

Comment: Your code seems to do it well

Comment: the problem is that it doen't end, am having a hard time to find a code for a false statement that will make it stop.

Comment: It's just a matter of definition. For example you can decide that you stop once a user enters a `'.'` character.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could make use of [std::set<>](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/set/).

"*Sets are a kind of associative container that stores unique elements* <...> *elements in a set are always sorted from lower to higher following a specific strict weak ordering criterion set*"

Answer (score 0):

It would be much more efficient to create an array of size 128 (assuming you are dealing with ASCII) that is initialized with `false`. Every time you get a character, check its ASCII value and if the array is true on that value you don't print it. After that, update the value of the array on the character value to true. Something like:

```
bool *seenArray = new bool[128]();

void onkey(char input) {
    if(((int)input) < 0) return;
    if (!seenArray[(int)input]) {
         myArray[count] = input;
         count++;
         seenArray[(int)input] = true;
    }         
}
```

Comment: ASCII only defines values in the range [0, 127).

Comment: Bug: If there is non-ASCII input, the `if` line does an access out of the array bounds, and you get undefined behavior. Fix by adding `if(int(input) < 0) return;` to the start of `onkey`.

Comment: @idanzalz: If you write `bool *seenArray = new bool[128]();`, it will initialize all elements to `false`. No need to use a `for` loop for that. Notice the braces `()` in `new bool[128]()`. Also, `bool[] seenArray` is ill-formed. It should be `bool *seenArray`.

Answer (score 0):

Looking through your code...

```
char myArray [500];
```

Why 500? You never use more than 8.

```
char num;
```

Confusing naming. Most programmers would expect a variable named `num` to be a numeric type (e.g. `int` or `float`).

```
while (entered < 8)
```

Consider replacing `8` with a constant (e.g. `const int kMaxEntered = 8;`).

```
cin >> num;
```

`cin` might be line-buffered; i.e. it does nothing until a whole line is entered.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
    if (myArray[i] == num)
        duplicate=true;
}
```

You're accessing uninitialized elements of `myArray`. Hint: your loop size should not be 8.

Consider using `continue;` if you find a duplicate.

```
if (!duplicate)
{
    myArray[count] = num;
    count++;
} // end if
else
    cout << num << " character has already been entered\n\n";
```

Your `// end if` comment is incorrect. The `if` isn't ended until the `else` is done.

You may want to add braces around the `else` clause, or remove the braces from the `if` clause by combining its two lines into the one-line `myArray[count++] = num;`.

```
// prints the list of values
cout<<"The final Array Contains:\n";

for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    cout << myArray[i] << " ";
}
```

You're printing the list every time you get a single input?

Don't use `\n` in text to `cout` unless you specifically want to micromanage buffering. Instead, use `endl`. Also, always put spaces around binary operators like `<<` and don't randomly capitalize words:

```
cout << "The final array contains:" << endl;
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    cout << myArray[i] << " ";
cout << endl;
```